# linux kernel module not autoloading

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I'm studing the linux kernel and start with hello world module at this point everything is fine but after compile

```
$ make
```

and install

```
$ insmod akmod.ko
```

the module it's not showing a "hello world" message on KERN_DEBUG

```
$ dmesg
nothing here
$
```

just show on rmmod

```
$ rmmod akmod
[4543.3423432] hello world
[5462.5323452] goodbye
```

The code is the same found here: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-2-sect-2

I just changed the KERN_ALERT for KERN_DEBUG

I'm using Debian 8.

I think that occurs because the module it´s not autoloading on **insmod**

When I run

```
$ make menuconfig
```

I can't find the option **Automatic kernel module loading**

```
Loadable module support  --->
  [*] Enable loadable module support
  [*]   Module unloading
  [ ]   Module versioning support (EXPERIMENTAL)
  [*]   Automatic kernel module loading **(My menu config don´t show this option)**
```

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: You're loading it manually. What would autoloading have to do with it?

Comment: I don't know, lol, I really want to understand why my module only show the message on rmmod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like you did not include a newline ("\n") at the end of your printk.

Since you didn't share your actual code and your insmod is obviously not from the example. (insmod akmod.ko? Why akmod? akmod is a completely different thing.) debugging this is a complete guess.

Comment: Indeed I put a new line (\n) and it´s print the message on loading (using KERN_DEBUG). But using the tips of @Tyvarev (KERN_INFO and KERN_DEBUG) the message has printed without the new line (\n) caracter.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is some delay between issuing `printk` and showing message in dmesg. You can see that from dmesg output: timestamp for "hello world" is 80 seconds lesser than one for "goodbye".

Do not know exatctly why, but the more level of the message, the lesser delay. You can try KERN_INFO or even KERN_ALERT.

Comment: I don't believe that this is true. Look at what printk and dmesg do internally, it is a static-allocated memory block that is written immediately by printk. dmesg just dumps out the memory block. There are never delays.