# journalctl updates with every other message

Tags: kernel-module, archlinux, systemd

I am working on my first kernel module. I've completed a few exercises in The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide but this is my first one without any guidance.

When I print messages using printk or the pr_err macro journalctl doesn't catch up until I print another message.

For example

```
int init_module()
{
    pr_err("This is a message");
}

void cleanup_module()
{
    pr_err("this is a second message");
}
```

If I insmod this module journalctl will show nothing. When I rmmod journalctl will show both messages and the timestamp will be the same.

If I insmod this module then insmod another module that prints both messages will show after I insmod the second module. The timestamp will be the same for both messages.

Comment: Seems to be same issue as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141434/linux-kernel-module-not-autoloading). (While referenced question is asked before, it is hardly can be found via search because of wording. This question looks more elaborate.)

Answer (score 0):

If message for `printk` doesn't contain newline symbol, its output can be delayed.

Normally, you need

```
pr_err("This is a message\n");
```

Sometimes, using `KERN_INFO` or `KERN_ALERT` also force message to be output immediately. But approach with terminating `\n` seems to be more clear.

Taken from answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141434/linux-kernel-module-not-autoloading).